# Opening a window in a horizontal split of a vertical split

Tags: vim

I want have both NERDTree and TagList open at the same time, but I don't need for them to have the whole height of the screen. Instead I would like to have them split horizontally within a single vertical split.

More specifically, I want to be able to open one, say NERDTree, and have it take up the full height of the screen. Then when I open TagList, to have it horizontally split with the already open NERDTree window.

Is there a way to do this? Possibly even a non 'specific to these two plugins' way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NERDTree and Taglist aren't going to open inside splits.

Let's say you have a split buffer on the left (for eg. source code), and Taglist on the right.

You can put this in a function, and invoke it with a mapping:

```
NERDTree    " open NERDTree
wincmd J    " move NERDTree to the very bottom
wincmd k    " move the cursor to the above split (the source code buffer)
wincmd H    " move the split to the very left
wincmd l    " move the cursor back to the NERDTree split
resize 20   " resize the split height to 20
exe 'vertical resize ' . g:NERDTreeWinSize    " reset the split width
```

This is pretty dodgy, but it works. You'll see a brief visual glitch while the split jumps around the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal split:

```
:split
```

Vertical split:

```
:vsplit
```

Then when you have split your screen how you prefer, open nerdtree inside the desired frame.
(Or you can use abbreviation :sp :vsp like suggested by @Vivek Pandey).

Comment: :sp and :vsp would save a few key strokes (they uniquely expand to :split and :vsplit)

Comment: How do you open either of these plugins in a specific window?

Comment: First you split the window. then go into desired window and open the desired plugin

Comment: Is there some way of doing this I don't know about? The only way I know of opening the plugins opens them in a new split, not in the current window

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a solution in a duplicate post here:
[NERDTree & TList in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173082/open-nerdtree-and-tlist-above-each-other-in-vim/8176267#8176267)

It involves editing the 'taglist.vim' script a bit to add a new split option when opening.