# Open NERDTree and Tlist above each other in Vim

Tags: vim, nerdtree, tlist

I'm looking for a way to (automatically) open NERDTree and Tlist on the left side directly above each other, so that each plugin takes up half of the screen height. I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005874/opening-a-window-in-a-horizontal-split-of-a-vertical-split), in which the answer of Mohammed is kind of what I'm looking for. However, I'm wondering if maybe there is a more direct way of doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a window in a horizontal split of a vertical split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005874/opening-a-window-in-a-horizontal-split-of-a-vertical-split)

Comment: @lucapette Yeah, of course it's kind of a duplicate. But that question didn't receive a satisfying answer and hasn't seen any activity in a couple of months. So how would I go about reactivating that question, other than extending it to a new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires a small edit to the 'taglist.vim' script.  I haven't worked out all the potential ramifications, but it seems to work nicely so far.  Modify the 'Tlist_Window_Create' function in 'taglist.vim' to include the `elseif` statement shown here:

```
...
" Create a new window. If user prefers a horizontal window, then open
" a horizontally split window. Otherwise open a vertically split
" window
if g:Tlist_Use_Horiz_Window
    " Open a horizontally split window
    let win_dir = 'botright'
    " Horizontal window height
    let win_size = g:Tlist_WinHeight
elseif g:Tlist_Use_Split_Window
    " Open the window in a horizontal split  of current window
    let win_dir = 'abo'
    let win_size = g:Tlist_WinWidth
else
...
```

I inserted this starting at line 1290 in the latest TagList (v4.5).
Then add the following to your .vimrc

```
let Tlist_Use_Split_Window = 1
com TT NERDTree | TlistToggle
```

Now the `:TT` command opens the TagList above the NERDTree in a single vertical window.  As is it doesn't quite split halfway, but it's close.  If you prefer the tree on top change the `abo` above to `split`.

Comment: also, the TT you've defined doesn't completely toggle NERDTree-ideally, using TT either way should either open them both, and close them both.

Comment: @Adam It looks like if you use NERDTreeToggle instead of NERDTree when defining TT, it will close NERDTree appropriately.  However, this only works if you use 'abo' for win_dir.  If you use 'split', taglist will complain about the window not being open and open a new window, which messes things up (but if you do use 'split' the windows are split halfway).  What I have defined after the TT definition is `noremap <S-Space> :TT<CR><C-w>=` - this resizes all windows equally on show or hide, but typically this is what I want anyway.