# VIM: how to open NERDTree in specific position

Tags: vim

With :NERDTree, the explorer window is open vertically left.  But I want it open in horizontally bottom. How do I archive this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a window in a horizontal split of a vertical split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005874/opening-a-window-in-a-horizontal-split-of-a-vertical-split)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+NERDTree+horizontal